# How to create a chart that displays two measurement values in Python?

Tags: python, charts, measure

I am trying to create a chart where I want to display sales as a bar and profits using colour. The bars will be used to inform the sales figures (taller bars mean higher sales). But at the same time, the bar will be used to inform the profits too using a colour. Higher profits mean darker shade of a colour, lower profits mean a lighter shade of the colour. I do not have any restrictions on using different colours so green, amber and red are also fine (in that case I need to define the ranges, eg., between 75 and 100: green, between 25 and 74.99: amber and anything below 25 as red).
How can I achieve this in Python, please?
Thank you.
Best wishes,
Manoj.

Comment: Matplotlib is typically uses for plotting graphs. Within matplotlib, You can use a cmap to map values to colors - https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html - and use this cmap to set the color of the bar plots.

Comment: Thanks @TomMcLean. I shall explore this route. 
Best regards.